# YII framework and postgres: get the next sequence value

Tags: postgresql, yii, sequence

I use yii with postrgres. Is it possible to get the next (or current) sequence value via yii's ORM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To all of those smartasses who minused my question: [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#getLastInsertID-detail) is the right answer.